# set website background is google map iframe code

Tags: html, css, google-maps

i need set ***iframe*** website background like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umwLH.png)

i went to show embed google map in background and add any think up it

```
 <div id='map-canvas'><iframe
          class="custom-google-map"
          src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1pqr-Kg5Dn8CyoomMIP2j7160niTmiTRi"
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
        ></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove iframe and add only this

```
<div id='map-canvas'></div>
```

And then Add this script in your html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
}
```

also add this css

```
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  bottom: -200px; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  z-index: 0;
}

#container {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
}
```